# C++/C Best way to detect when a folder contents changed and send the files that do via HTTP

Tags: c++, c, upload

What's the best way to scan a folder and be notified when a new file has been created. I'm using Windows XP and I need a solution in C++ or C.
I need to send those files via HTTP to the server.

Wondering what would be the best solution for this? open to using some third party library.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FindFirstChangeNotification function with FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME as last argument.

It will return you a handler which then you need to observe with WaitForSingleObject.
This second function will wait for a specified amound of time or for a notification from a handler.

If you would like to break it manualy, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects instead and provide two handles: first handle is the one you get from FindFirstChangeNotification, and the second can be a handler from your own event (use CreateEvent to create it) which you can trigger with SetEvent(handle_you_get_from_CreateEvent)

Comment: @TrevorDonahue the suggested functions are part of WindowsAPI. See MS docs for [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: ok, here's me trying to compile this piece of code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx
gives me the error:
`main.cpp: In function 'void WatchDirectory(LPTSTR)':
main.cpp:39:81: error: '_tsplitpath_s' was not declared in this scope`

I also defined the UNICODE and _UNICODE macros as explained here:
[**(WinAPI: Being Unicode Friendly)**](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/16820/)

Comment: maybe this function is not declared in proper header in WinXP. I encourage you to try to write it whole by yourself. Debbuger is your friend :)